# How would I properly autowire this class and applicatonContext.xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired, applicationcontext

I am fairly new to using Spring. I understand the concept of autowiring, but am confused on the implementation. I have a Maven multi-module project, and I am trying to Autowire the manager class in Module A so that I can use it in Module B. When I try to run the webapp, I get an error along the lines of:

```
No matching bean of type [com..Manager] found for               dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as             autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

Module A (jar):
Manager.java

```
public interface Manager
{...}
```

ManagerImpl.java

```
@Service(value="manager")
public class ManagerImpl implements Manager
{...}
```

Module B (war):
WebController.java

```
@Controller
public class WebController
{

@Autowired
private Manager manager;

..}
```

applicationContext.xml (in Module A)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c" xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com....si" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As module B has dependency for module A and module A has it's own application context file called applicationContext.xml , then make sure applicationContext.xml is getting bundled with module A jar to place it in classpath.

Now you need to add ContextLoaderListener in Module B web.xml,

```
   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>
              classpath*:/<package folder structure in jar>/applicationContext.xml      
          </param-value>
   </context-param>

   <listener>
       <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
```

Also you need to add following lines in both xmls , **applicationContext.xml and mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="<packages for stereotype>" />
```

With this, bean should get injected.

Comment: The use of <context:component-scan> implicitly enables the functionality of <context:annotation-config>. There is usually no need to include the <context:annotation-config> element when using <context:component-scan>. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-autodetection

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `<context:annotation-config/>` to your applicationContext.xml. 
I've always included both to ensure complete scanning of the project.  In addition, is the field you are trying to autowire within the base-package for the component scan?

Answer (score 0):

The first thingh you have to do is to instantiate the "Manager", in order to perform the mapping between interface and implementation:

```
<bean id="ManagerBean" class="[package.].ManagerImpl/>
```

Then you have to instantiate the "Controller", in order to perform the mapping between manager and the ManagerImpl class

```
<bean id="Controller" class="[package.]WebController.java">
    <property name="manager" ref="ManagerBean" />
</bean>
```

Edit: both pieces of code should be placed in the xml

Comment: The manager and managerImpl class are in Module A's applicationContext and the WebController.java is in Module B. I only have a mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml in B. So I would put the bean id="Controller" in that xml?